# Using ggraph's circlepack layout in R

Tags: r, circle-pack, ggraph

I am trying to create a graph using ggraph's circlepack layout in R.

The code I am using is below.

```
df <- data.frame(PID = c("root", "c11111", "c22222", "c11111", "c11111"),    
                 ID = c("c11111", "c22222", "s33333", "c44444", "c55555"), 
                 size = c(1, 20000, 10000, 1, 1))

vertices <- df %>% 
  distinct(ID, size) %>% 
  add_row(ID = "root", size = 0)

mygraph <- graph_from_data_frame(df, vertices = vertices)

ggraph(mygraph, layout = 'circlepack') +
  geom_node_circle(aes(fill = size)) +
  theme_void() +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name))
```

I am not sure why c22222 is not appearing within c33333 - I'm only seeing c33333.

I'd greatly appreciate any advice or ideas about what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually correct, but your labels are overlapping
If you add some jitter to your plot you'll see c22222

```
ggraph(mygraph, layout = 'circlepack') +
  geom_node_circle(aes(fill = size)) +
  theme_void() +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name),position=position_jitter(width=.2,height=.2))
```

Note this plot currently does not use the `size` property of your graph.
You should add `weight=size`

```
ggraph(mygraph, layout = 'circlepack', weight=size)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. After adding jitter to the plot, I now see the label for c22222. However, it it is not appearing as a distinct circle within c33333 - any ideas?